# Filter criteria are not working with featured content blocks

Tags: views

I am trying to create a featured content block for my front page. To start I have set up a "featured" vocabulary with the two terms 'featured', and 'not featured'. I have then added that field to all my content types that I use.

Now when constructing the view to get all content that has the 'featured' term works if in the filter criteria it has only one content type.
For example if I put the filter criteria to only check against the book term, then it brings back all book pages with the featured term.  However, if I set up the filter criteria to check for book page feature, or article page feature, no content is found.

Is there a limitation on mixing content filtering in this way?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You probably have a views setting wrong. You could remove the content-type filter to see if the taxonomy term filter alone is working. For the content-type filter you just choose "Is One Of" and then select your content-types in the list.

Comment: Thanks for replying - It is working when just retrieving just one content type, it is when you add the or filter for another content type.  I have uploaded 2 screenshots to illustrate my point - there might be something I am missing :p
[working](http://fullcircleproductions.co.uk/filters-working.jpg)
[not working](http://fullcircleproductions.co.uk/filters-not_working.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in this case you don't need to add your filters to a new filter group, because views will use AND by default.

I don't see a filter for your taxonomy term. You should add one (see in the attached images).

For the content types you need just one filter, you can select which content types to filter on inside the filter.

[image: Example Configuration Views Block]

[image: Example Taxonomy Term Filter]

[image: Example Content Type Filter]

Comment: You are absolutely right :)  I don't know why I didn't look for filtering just on the taxonomy term o.O  Thank you :)